# I got error java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.tnmd.learningenglishapp.screens.list_courses.CoursesViewModel

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, android-jetpack-compose, dagger-hilt

I am building an Android application using Jetpack compose library with Firebase. I'm rebuilding the app based on this sample builder [Make it so android](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/make-it-so-android)

When I executed the program it gave me the following error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.tnmd.learningenglishapp, PID: 6542                                                                                                java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Cannot create an instance of class com.tnmd.learningenglishapp.screens.list_courses.CoursesViewModel
at androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.ViewModelKt.viewModel(ViewModel.kt:120)
at com.tnmd.learningenglishapp.screens.list_courses.CoursesScreenKt.CoursesScreen(CoursesScreen.kt:66)
at com.tnmd.learningenglishapp.ComposableSingletons$LearningEnglishAppKt$lambda9$1.invoke(LearningEnglishApp.kt:160)
at com.tnmd.learningenglishapp.ComposableSingletons$LearningEnglishAppKt$lambda-9$1.invoke(LearningEnglishApp.kt:159)
```

**1. CoursesScreen.kt**

```
package com.tnmd.learningenglishapp.screens.list_courses

@SuppressLint("UnusedMaterialScaffoldPaddingParameter")
@Composable
@ExperimentalMaterialApi
fun CoursesScreen(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    viewModel: CoursesViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {
    Scaffold(
        floatingActionButton = {
            FloatingActionButton(
                onClick = { /*viewModel.onUpdateClick(openScreen)*/ },
                backgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colors.primary,
                contentColor = MaterialTheme.colors.onPrimary,
                modifier = modifier.padding(16.dp)
            ) {
                Icon(Icons.Filled.Add, "Update")
            }
        }
    ) {
        val courses = viewModel.courses.collectAsStateWithLifecycle(emptyList())

        Column(modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .fillMaxHeight()) {
            LazyColumn {
                items(courses.value, key = { it.id }) { coursesItem ->
                    CoursesItem(
                        coursesItem
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**2. CoursesViewModel.kt**

```
package com.tnmd.learningenglishapp.screens.list_courses

class CoursesViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val coursesService: CoursesService,
    logService: LogService
) : LearningEnglishAppViewModel(logService){

    val courses = coursesService.courses


    fun onUpdateClick(openScreen: (String) -> Unit) = openScreen(ACCOUNT_UPDATE)


 /*   fun onCourseActionClick(openScreen: (String) -> Unit, task: Task, action: String) {
        when (TaskActionOption.getByTitle(action)) {
            TaskActionOption.EditTask -> openScreen("$EDIT_TASK_SCREEN?$TASK_ID={${task.id}}")
            TaskActionOption.ToggleFlag -> onFlagTaskClick(task)
            TaskActionOption.DeleteTask -> onDeleteTaskClick(task)
        }
    }*/

}
```

3. **CoursesService.kt**

```
package com.tnmd.learningenglishapp.model.service

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task
import com.tnmd.learningenglishapp.model.Account
import com.tnmd.learningenglishapp.model.Courses
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow

interface CoursesService {
    val courses: Flow<List<Courses>>
    suspend fun getCourses(coursesId: String): Courses?
    suspend fun save(courses: Courses): String
    suspend fun update(courses: Courses)
    suspend fun delete(coursesId: String)
}
```

This is not an obvious error so I can find out the cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the `@HiltViewModel` annotation to your viewmodel so it has to be like this:

```
    @HiltViewModel
    class CoursesViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val coursesService: CoursesService,
    logService: LogService
) : LearningEnglishAppViewModel(logService){

    val courses = coursesService.courses


    fun onUpdateClick(openScreen: (String) -> Unit) = openScreen(ACCOUNT_UPDATE)


 /*   fun onCourseActionClick(openScreen: (String) -> Unit, task: Task, action: String) {
        when (TaskActionOption.getByTitle(action)) {
            TaskActionOption.EditTask -> openScreen("$EDIT_TASK_SCREEN?$TASK_ID={${task.id}}")
            TaskActionOption.ToggleFlag -> onFlagTaskClick(task)
            TaskActionOption.DeleteTask -> onDeleteTaskClick(task)
        }
    }*/

}
```